# Noether's Invariance for Heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, noethers-theorem

So we know from the [first law of thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676489/150174):

$$ dU = dQ + dW $$

where $U$ is internal energy, $Q$ is heat and $W$ is work done. From [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=Noether%27s%20theorem%20or%20Noether%27s%20first,1915%20and%20published%20in%201918.) we also know that conservation of internal energy relates to time translational invariance

$$ dU = 0 \implies \text{Time Translational Invariance}$$

I haven't seen this done yet but what invariance does one gain when

$$dQ = 0 \implies ?$$

Comment: I suspect it should be some invariance of spatial thermodynamic probabilities? In the reversible case? But how do I get that from Noether's theorem?

Comment: I'm not well versed in Noether's theorem, but from the little I know of it the conserved quantities seem to be state functions, whereas heat is a path function. I don't know that Noether's theorem would apply to something like Q. Is it even possible to come up with an action for a system that is coupled to surroundings?

Comment: If I think of the action as a minimization of an integral in the reversible case my answer does seem plausible. I would be willing to accept an answer which explains why the premise of the question is misled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can heat be thought as a type of Noether invariant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/517949/)

Comment: FWIW, the original [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) (and its Noether current formula) assume an action formulation. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51534/2451

Answer (score 1):

I shall be providing a partial answer. We will restrict ourselves to the reversible case:

$$ Q = TdS$$

But, we also know from Gibbs entropy formula:

$$S = -k_B\sum_i p_i \ln p_i$$

Thus, $dS = 0$ implies,

$$ 0 = \sum_i  (\ln p_i + 1 ) dp_i$$
Using  $\sum_i p_i = 1$
$$  0= \sum_i \ln p_i dp_i $$

Since $p_i \leq 1$ implies,

Either all the energy is in a particular energy state or there there is there is an invariance of thermodynamic probabilities.

**Note**: This derivation does not does apply in the irreversible case.